# Running a Jenkins Slave with different set of plugins compared to master node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to install plugins to a Jenkins Slave Node? I need to install a jenkins plugin to the slave node, but it should not be added to the master node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins can be installed only on master. I don't think plugins could be installed slave specific in Jenkins.

May be if you share your purpose of installing it in Slave node, we may think about the possibilities.

To my knowledge, It is pointless to installing plugins as slave specific.

Thanks,
Madhan